# Python dask_ml linear regression Multiple constant columns detected error

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, machine-learning, dask

I am using python with dask to create a logistic regression model, In order to speed up things when training.

I have x that is the feature array (numpy array) and y that is a label vector.

edit: 
The numpy arrays are: x_train (n*m size) array of floats and the y_train is (n*1) vector of integers that are labels for the training. both suits well into sklearn LogisticRegression.fit and working fine there.

I tried to use this code to create a pandas df then converting it to dask ddf and training on it like shown [here](https://dask-ml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

```
from dask_ml.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from dask import dataframe as dd
df["label"] = y_train
sd = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=3)
lr = LogisticRegression(fit_intercept=False)
lr.fit(sd, sd["label"])
```

But getting an error

> Could not find signature for add_intercept:

I found [this issue](https://github.com/dask/dask-ml/issues/84) on Gitgub

Explaining to use this code instead

```
from dask_ml.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from dask import dataframe as dd
df["label"] = y_train
sd = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=3)
lr = LogisticRegression(fit_intercept=False)
lr.fit(sd.values, sd["label"])
```

But I get this error

> ValueError: Multiple constant columns detected!

How can I use dask to train a logistic regression over data originated from a numpy array?

Thanks.

Comment: How you have created the `y_train`? How is the corresponding `x` values created? Please mention that as it is confusing.

Comment: x_train is a numpy array of numbers, and y_train is a numpy vector of labels (integers)

Comment: But you have not mentioned in the question what are the contents of the x_train and y_train?

Comment: @AmazingThingsAroundYou I edited the question, But the origin of the numpy array is not relevant to this question, this is an API issue

Answer (score 1):

You can bypass std verification by using

```
lr = LogisticRegression(solver_kwargs={"normalize":False})
```

Or you can use @Emptyless code to get faulty column_indices
and then remove those columns from your array.

Answer (score 0):

This does not seem like an issue with `dask_ml`. Looking at the [source](https://github.com/dask/dask-glm/blob/master/dask_glm/utils.py), the `std` is calculated using:

```py
mean, std = da.compute(X.mean(axis=0), X.std(axis=0))
```

This means that for every column in your provided array, `dask_ml` calculates the standard deviation. If the standard deviation of one of those columns is equal to zero (`np.where(std == 0))`) that means that that column has zero variation.

Including a column with zero variation does not allow any training, ergo it needs to be removed prior to training the model (in a data preparation / cleansing step).

You can quickly check which columns have no variation by checking the following:

```py
import numpy as np

std = sd.std(axis=0)
column_indices = np.where(std == 0)
print(column_indices)
```

Comment: I do thing it's a dask issue, you should be able to train a model on data that has a column with zero variance, a lot of models training is based on deep learning feature extraction, where a column of the data can easily be all 0's

Comment: You can submit an issue or pull request to `dask_ml` and propose a new `**kwarg` that would allow this behavior and strip these columns inside the `LinearRegression`. I believe however that this is more in the data preparation / cleansing phase. However, at least this provides some insight in why it would fail and how to continue in the mean time.

Comment: This is definitely an API issue. Zero variance columns should be ignored during the training process and assigned a coefficient of 0.

Answer (score 0):

A little late to the party but here I go anyway. Hope future readers appreciate it. This answer is for the *Multiple Columns* error.

A **Dask DataFrame** is split up into many Pandas DataFrames. These are called partitions. If you set your npartitions to 1 it should have exactly the same effect as sci-kit learn. If you set it to more partitions it splits it into multiple DataFrames but I found it changes the shape of the DataFrames which in the end resulted in the *Multiple Columns* error. It also might cause a overflow warning. Unfortunately it is not in my interest to investigate the direct cause of this error. It might simply be because the DataFrame is too large or too small.

[A source for partitioning](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-best-practices.html)

Below the errors for search engine indexing:

- `ValueError: Multiple constant columns detected!`
- `RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in exp return np.exp(A)`